# How to hide anchor tag from URL

Tags: php, javascript, html, anchor

How can I hide the hash value from the following link href in the address bar?

```
<a href="index.php#dev_name">
```

So it'll redirect me to a the `index.php#dev_name`, but I want the address bar to only show `index.php`

Comment: What have you tried? Use JavaScript to jump to the required element without specifying it in the hash tag.

Comment: I tried to create a javascipt function which will redirect me directly on the wanted div: 
        function remove_anchor(){
            window.location.hash="div_name";
        }

and I added :
 
         <body onload="remove_anchor()";>

But it still display on the URL page1.php#div_name

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Javascript onclick event. The browser will still show `index.php`, but the onclick event will trigger first, and redirect the browser to the right page.

```
<a href="index.php" onclick="location.redirect('index.php#dev');">
```

Comment: I have to ask, why do you want to do this? Normally it's considered a bad practice to break standard behavior. There may be a couple good reasons to do this (Google does something similar on their search results, as an example), but I am wondering why you want to.

Comment: I have 2 uses : the first one I hav a logo for which I want if I click on it it redirect me to this div,
The second one is for my sub menu page in which I want once I click on one of the it redirect me directly on a div for the div wanted of the page

Comment: I'm pretty sure I read your question wrong. I thought you meant don't show the real address in the status bar. To do what you want to do, look into the Javascript `window.scrollTo()` function.