# Hide anchor tag from url

Tags: php, javascript, html, anchor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to hide anchor tag from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045303/how-to-hide-anchor-tag-from-url)

I have a menu which contains submenus, I want that onclick if each submenu, that will redirect me on a div of the php page :

For example if I want to go from :

Menu Menu1 --> Submenu1 I want that onclick of my sbmenu1 it redirect my on a div on page1#div_name without dipslay on the URL : www.page1.php#div_name, I just want www.page1.php

```
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="page1.php#div_name">Submenu1</a></li>
                <li><a href="page2.php#div_name">Submenu2</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Anchors are a well-defined part of the web, bypassing them is mostly just asking for trouble.

Comment: i do agree with @amber BTw http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-rewriting-the-browser-address-without-refresh see if this discussion helps

Comment: This question is also covered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045303/how-to-hide-anchor-tag-from-url

Comment: can I do this with javascript?

Comment: why twice the same question @soft_developer

Comment: @soft_developer not well explainned by whom? you or other peers if it is not explainned clearly by you, you can edit the question right away and if answer was not explained well by peers then you can ask for clarification in the comments

Comment: I don't feel anymore willing to answer after such a downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery scrollto plugin. If the link is not local you may set a cookie using javascript so when the new page loads you can read it and scroll the page.

Comment: How can I do this? I'm not good with jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the URL after it completes loading

```
window.history.pushState(“object or string”, “Title”, “page.php”);
```

FOr more info, check [this](http://spoiledmilk.dk/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can't override it. And any "solution" you do find that overrides it will break at some point. If you don't like hash strings in the URL, use url rewriting at the apache level.